# Using one AdMob AdRequest for multiple AdViews?

Tags: android, admob, adview

I have an Android app which has a few AdViews and every AdView has its own AdRequest so far. But is it possible/recommendable to use just one AdRequest for every AdView? Does that even make a difference? (Of course it makes a difference, but is it worth thinking about?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same `AdRequest` for multiple requests.  It is just a simple object that contains some meta-information about the ad you want to load.

Remember that only one AdView can be shown on an activity.  If you really want to have a static AdRequest object used across different activities, that would work.  But it's probably just as easy to create a new Request each time you want to load an ad.